# Can I have a SSL cert for a sub-domain in Lightsail if I already have a cert for the main domain in certificate manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns-zone, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

In AWS I have a domain (lets call it www.mydomain.com) which I have a SSL cert in certificate manager and the DNS records in Route 53.

In AWS Lightsail I have an instance with a loadbalancer and generated a Lightsail SSL cert for subdomain.mydomain.com and added the DNS records to a Lightsail DNS zone.

Is it ok to have a subdomain with SSL cert and DNS records in Lightsail when its parent domain has a cert in Certificate manager and DNS records in Route 53? Should this work? So far it does not seem to work for me. Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong here would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working. The part that slowed me down was I tried to use an A record in Route 53 with a plain IPv4. I spotted that there is an alias on the load balancer and used that instead and it all worked.

So the answer to my main question is yes. Just make sure to use the alias provided by the Lightsail load-balancer for your A record in Route 53.